# how to get list from json data in java

Tags: java, json, api, list, rest

**My Json Data:**

```
{'ID':1,'FirstName':'x','LastName':'y','Company':'x','EMail':'x','PhoneNo':'x'}
```

**My Java Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String json = getJSON().substring(getJSON().indexOf("[")+1,getJSON().indexOf("]"));
    Users user = new Gson().fromJson(json, Users.class);
    WriteLine("["+user.getID()+"]"+" "+user.getFirstName()+" "+user.getLastName()+" "+user.getCompany()+" "+user.getEMail()+" "+user.getPhoneNo());
}

static void WriteLine(String text){
    System.out.print(text);
}

static String getJSON() throws IOException
{
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:51679/api/User");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        sBuilder.append(line);
    }
    reader.close();
    connection.disconnect();
    return sBuilder.toString();
}
```

But my json data As these become:

```
{'ID':1,'FirstName':'x','LastName':'x','Company':'x','EMail':'x','PhoneNo':'x'},{'ID':2,'FirstName':'y','LastName':'y','Company':'y','EMail':'x','PhoneNo':'y'}
```

I have a error: Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 136

Can you help me? Sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the error message carefully. **That input is not valid JSON,** which is exactly what the message tells you. Strings and keys must be surrounded with **double quotes,** not single quotes:

```
{"ID":1,"FirstName":"x","LastName":"y","Company":"x","EMail":"x","PhoneNo":"x"}
```

A simple check with [a JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com/) would tell you the same. Alternately – again, as the error message conveniently tells you – you could set the reader to be lenient with [`JsonReader.setLenient(true)`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html#setLenient%28boolean%29), to hopefully accept malformed JSON as input.